# Combine multiple tables in one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have tlb1 as :

```
col1

1

2

3
```

Now I have tlb2 as:

```
col2   col3

 4     Four  

 5     Five  

 6     SIX
```

No I have tlb3 as

```
   col4          col5

    sample14     sample15

    sample24     sample25

    sample34     sample35
```

What can be the query if I want result as :

```
col1 col2   col3   col4       col5     

1     4     Four   sample14   sample15 

2     5     Five   sample24   sample25

3     6     Six    sample34   sample35
```

I tried with :

```
select ( (select * from tlb1), (select * from tlb2),(select * from tlb3)) T
```

But this failed.

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to combine completely unrelated data? What to do if different number of rows in the tables?

Comment: different number of rows are only creating problem..

Comment: Yes, you see! Still think this is a good idea?

Comment: Bearing in mind that there is no order in the data, what is the common factor between the tables that you want to join on? Again, you cannot say "row order" because there is not one.

Comment: there is no common factor in data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 with t1 as (select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn from tbl1 ),
 t2 as (select col2,col3, row_number() over (order by col2) rn from tbl2),
 t3 as (  select col4,col5, row_number() over (order by col4) rn  from tbl3) 
 select t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col4,t3.col5 
 from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
 t3 full outerjoin t2 on t2.rn = t3.rn
```

try something like this...

Comment: Yes this is somewhat working for me.. If any dificulty i will get back to you